# Functions for subview abstracted to different .h and .m files

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have MasterViewController.h and MasterViewController.m files and within those files I load a subview on top of part of that view when the a button is pressed. I want the functions of that subview (IBActions, etc.) to be in different files (ContactUs.h and ContactUs.m) so I can abstract this program and break it into smaller/simpler pieces.

How can I go about doing this? The .xib file is loaded in the MasterViewController.m with:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed@"ContactUs_GeneralContact" owner:self options[NSDictionary dictionary]];
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new subclass of `UIView` (via File - New ) and move the methods to the new subclass.
- open your xib in Interface Builder
- in the inspector on the right select the identity inspector and insert your class name as custom class

All done.

[image]

Comment: Hmm I need MasterViewController to be the owner because ContactUs_GeneralContact.xib is an IBOutlet of that file due to a custom animation of the subview. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i have understood your question:)...What you can do is take two view controllers 1. MasterViewController 
2. ContactUsViewController 
and two Views 
1. MasterView(MasterViewController's View) main view
2. ContactUsView(ContactUsController's View) subview which is loaded on top

Write what ever function u need 
in ContactUsViewController

## import it in MasterViewController , instantiate it when ever you want and load it where ever you want:):)

Thus Master and ContactUs are completely independent of each other..:)have a nice day